# react-router - creating nested routes with no Component nesting

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route config like this.

```
<Route path="group/:groupId" component={NonPropertyView}>
<Route path="group/:groupId/line/:lineId" component={NonPropertyView} />
<Route path="group/:groupId/line/:lineId/property/:propertyId" component={PropertyView} />
```

But can I do this ?

```
<Route path="group/:groupId" component={NonPropertyView}>
  <Route path="line/:lineId" component={NonPropertyView}>
    <Route path="property/:propertyId" component={PropertyView} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

What I am looking for is an option to just render `Component` for leaf Route without rendering a parent route `Component`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes - use `<IndexRoute>`s. For example, write the above as:

```js
<Route path="group/:groupId">
  <IndexRoute component={NonPropertyView} />
  <Route path="line/:lineId">
    <IndexRoute component={NonPropertyView} />
    <Route path="property/:propertyId" component={PropertyView} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```